# Disable Google Chrome Auto Update in Windows 11

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, windows-11

I want to disable automatic updates to Google Chrome because I am interested in the Google Chrome 94.0.4606.54 version in order to use selenium ChromeOptions.

1. I've tried renaming the Google Chrome update folderchanging: replacing the name of the "**Update**" folder it actually stops the momentary update, but when I turn off/on the computer the system has now re-updated chrome and a new "**Update**" folder has been replaced.
2. I've tried to disable automatic Chrome updates from the **Windows System Configuration** or the **Windows Services Manager** but there is no Google Update Service in there.

Any Help? (I don't know if this has anything to do with it, but when I download Chrome, it is saved in "Local" and not in "Program Files (x86)")

Answer (score 3):

I find mine solution to make updates completely manual. I think this method is more universal and more robust.

So, there is 2 things you need to do, first one is go into **Services** and find 2 services with names Google Update: `gupdate` and `gupdatem`, open their properties and select launch type: `disabled`.

This way it will not able to service to run. However this wont prevent updating entirely.

Now for second part you should go to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google`. Make sure to enable to show file extensions, so that you would see `GoogleUpdate.exe`

Now, rename it, I suggest also rename extension, e.g. `GoogleUpdate_._exe`

*The reason why I suggesting to keep it, if you will need manually update your browser, you can do that by renaming it back and run manual update from browser about page.*

Now, create new empty text file and rename it in place of `GoogleUpdate.exe`, so that you will have zero-bytes executable. After that open file properties and go in **Security** tab and hit **Edit** permissions button.
*Since my OS in different language I can't provide exact screenshots, but you can see it from [this article](https://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/set-file-folder-permissions-windows/), if you need visual guidance.*

In new dialog you should go in each options: whether it `SYSTEM`, `Administrators`, `Users` or your account and in checkboxes below click on **Full control** - **Deny** ✅, so that you remove every possible option to either read, write or execute this application. After that hit **Ok**.

This become a really great protection. You see, even if you double-click this exe file as user or administrator you will see permission error. If you try to edit it, you will also get this error, same will be if you try to rename it. This way you prevent it to run at whatever costs.

After that when I run browser again, I get a popup that Chrome cannot update and it thinks that installation is corrupted and suggest reinstall Chrome. This is really a good sign because it shows that Chrome trying to sneakily run update in background, but failed to run it.

## If you want to manually update

Open permissions for exe again, remove checkmarks from deny, delete or rename this temp file and put real update executable on it's place. Then open services and make run type back to demand. Run Chrome, and go into about page, do update, then close Chrome, stop services (or check that there 2 Google Update processes in background and terminate them both), disable services again. Do renaming executable again and place this file with denying permissions on it's place.

Comment: This solution fixed the issue. Now the Chrome browser is no longer upgrading.

Answer (score 2):

My solution was to add a new line to `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` file

```
127.0.0.1 tools.google.com
```

This update overrides the ip of the google's update server.

Answer (score 0):

Two pottential approach to ***disable*** automatic [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) auto update in [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) systems are:

- Rename the application ***GoogleUpdate*** (located at *`C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Update`*) to something else. Example: ***`GoogleUpdate2`***
- Rename the directory ***Update*** (located at *`C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\`*) to something else. Example: ***`Update3`***

[image: GoogleUpdate]

Comment: As I wrote, I already did it. But when I turn off/on the computer google chrome has been updated and a new "Update" folder has been added to the Google folder. However, when I download Chrome, it is saved in "Local" and not in "Program Files (x86)", I don't know if this has anything to do with it...